# Elastic Wrap Panel Breaks Scroll Viewer and doesn't play well with the others

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wrappanel

I have an elastic wrap panel that works great and exactly how I want. It allows me to have 2 columns with 'Stretched' controls and will wrap to one column if res gets small enough. Now the problem it gave me is it broke my scroll viewer. When it goes to one column the scrollviewer doesn't work and it doesn't work inside a stackpanel with other normal controls. I'm not sure what the fix here is but I do know that inheriting the 'Panel' is causing this problem though.

```
public class ElasticWrapPanel : Panel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Identifies the <see cref="DesiredColumnWidth"/> dependency property. 
    /// </summary>
    internal static readonly DependencyProperty DesiredColumnWidthProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("DesiredColumnWidth", typeof(double), typeof(ElasticWrapPanel), new PropertyMetadata(100d, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnDesiredColumnWidthChanged)));

    private int _columns;

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        _columns = (int)(availableSize.Width / DesiredColumnWidth);

        if (_columns > 2)
        {
            _columns = 2;
        }

        foreach (UIElement item in this.Children)
        {
            item.Measure(availableSize);
        }

        return base.MeasureOverride(availableSize);
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        if (_columns != 0)
        {
            double columnWidth = Math.Floor(finalSize.Width / _columns);

            double top = 0;
            double rowHeight = 0;
            int column = 0;
            foreach (UIElement item in this.Children)
            {
                item.Arrange(new Rect(columnWidth * column, top, columnWidth, item.DesiredSize.Height));
                column++;
                rowHeight = Math.Max(rowHeight, item.DesiredSize.Height);

                if (column == _columns)
                {
                    column = 0;
                    top += rowHeight;
                    rowHeight = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        return base.ArrangeOverride(finalSize);
    }

    private static void OnDesiredColumnWidthChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var panel = (ElasticWrapPanel)obj;
        panel.InvalidateMeasure();
        panel.InvalidateArrange();
    }

    public double DesiredColumnWidth
    {
        get
        {
            return (double)GetValue(DesiredColumnWidthProperty);
        }

        set
        {
            SetValue(DesiredColumnWidthProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
 <ScrollViewer>

    <StackPanel>

      <lib:ElasticWrapPanel DesiredColumnWidth="370" />

      <Button width="200" height="70" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />

    </StackPanel>

 </ScrollViewer>
```

Problem: The button doesn't stack it just gets placedd on top the panel. And when the wrap panel goes to one column of controls instead of 2, the scrollviewer doesn't enable. Its like it doesn't recognize anything around it or something. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Exchange `StackPanel` for `Grid` with respective columns and you should be good.

Comment: Unfortunatley that didn't work either.

Comment: Really? well shoot guess I might actually have to take a look then.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like the height in the ElasticWrapPanel is not updating properly. when reading out there is NaN in it.
If you adjust the MeasureOverride function as follows, it should work.

```
protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
{
    _columns = (int)(availableSize.Width / DesiredColumnWidth);

    if (_columns > 2)
    {
        _columns = 2;
    }

    double columnWidth = Math.Floor(availableSize.Width / _columns);

    double top = 0;
    double rowHeight = 0;
    int column = 0;

    foreach (UIElement item in this.Children)
    {
        // Adjust available size for each item based on column width
        Size itemAvailableSize = new Size(columnWidth, double.PositiveInfinity);
        item.Measure(itemAvailableSize);

        if (column == 0)
        {
            rowHeight = item.DesiredSize.Height;
        }

        if (column < _columns - 1)
        {
            column++;
        }
        else
        {
            column = 0;
            top += rowHeight;
            rowHeight = 0;
        }
    }

    double panelHeight = top + rowHeight;
    return new Size(availableSize.Width, panelHeight);
}
```

this adjusts the available size for each child element based on the column width. The height of the panel is set based on the calculated height of the elements and the number of rows.